# Facing error when running Spring MVC + Hibernate+ Rest API project

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, rest

Can anyone please help me with this error.

I am trying to run a project based on `Spring MVC` and `Rest API` with a hibernate MySQL database.
And facing error in JSP page user.jsp. I have tried to add a server in the build path, but this error is still not going away.

[Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MzaEV.png)